# How to Call onActivityResult in adapter listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onactivityresult

i'm learning how to change Single item with resultActivity in  in my custom Adapter listview. how it's can work ?

this my code when startActivityForResult in custom adapter listview

```
holder.isi_layout.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

                            Intent i = null;                                
                            i = new Intent(activity, DetailLaporanActivity.class);                              
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("position", Integer.toString(position));

                            i.putExtras(b);
                            activity.startActivityForResult(i, mRequestCode);                                  
                            activity.overridePendingTransition (R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);


        }
    });
```

and this OnResultActivity

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode==mRequestCode) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String position = data.getStringExtra("position");
                String status_favorite = data.getStringExtra("status_favorite");
                String jumlah_favorite = data.getStringExtra("jumlah_favorite");
                String jumlah_komentar = data.getStringExtra("jumlah_komentar");
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This code Success get Result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

When i put OnResultActivity in Adapter, code is error, **RESULT_OK** get notice **Cannot be resolved to a variable**,

but if i put in MainActivity , this not error but not get value result, i check with **Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This code Success get Result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();** but no toast,....

anybody help me ? how it's work ?
sorry, for my english...

Comment: can u pls help me my onActivityResult inside Adapter class is not being called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added unresolved RESULT_OK so you should set it in `DetailLaporanActivity.class` like that.

```
public class DetailLaporanActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);

  }
}
```

and than you can use RESULT_OK in your `onActivityResult` method.

Answer (score 2):

That's because RESULT_OK is a constant of the Activity class.  So, you need to qualify it in your Adapter class as so:

```
Activity.RESULT_OK
```

Comment: Cool!  I also think his solution is the real one.

Comment: Rick, your solution worked for me. Thanks. I think it had to do with extending a fragment, and not an Activity.